# QR Reader decoder как работать с большим расширением

Tags: python, python-3.x

Задача стоит найти qr code гдето в левом углу файла.

```
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
from PIL import Image #pip install Pillow 

d = decode(Image.open('photo.jpg'))

print(d[0].data.decode('ascii'))
```

Возникает ошибка: IndexError: list index out of range. Как исправить. Может есть другие готовые решения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему обрезанием картинки до нужной области.

```
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
from PIL import Image #pip install Pillow
import os

img = Image.open('001.jpg')
area = (150, 1680, 410, 2000)
cropped_img = img.crop(area)
cropped_img.save('002.jpg')

d = decode(Image.open('002.jpg'))

print(d[0].data.decode('ascii'))

os.remove("002.jpg")
```